# How to get the repository names for a particular selected branch using LibGit2Sharp library

Tags: c#, github, libgit2sharp

We are using LibGit2Sharp library to process the commits in Github.

**Issue**: We need to get all the repository names for the selected branch in Github through LibGit2Sharp library.

Which class will be having the collection of repository names for the particular branch.

We searched through the below LibGit2Sharp documentation but we did not get any idea.

http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Projects/LibGit2Sharp

Can anyone please propose any solution.

Comment: "We need to get all the repository names for the selected branch in Github": do you have an example of the input, and desired output?

Comment: What do you mean by "repository name" exactly? As is, the question is pretty unclear.

Comment: That is if we select the branch in Github it must list out all its repositories/Folders present under selected branch.

Comment: @Skyrim I would suggest you to go through these links - **[`Link 1`](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net)**  and **[`Link 2`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34488006/2065039)** Also this **[`Link`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505551/how-can-i-programmatically-detect-inactive-branches-in-github-repositories)** for your reference..

Comment: Do you want the names of all the files and folders beneath a single repository at a given branch?  It seems that you added a bounty without clarifying the question...

Comment: Yes Edward we need to list  the names of all the files and folders beneath a single repository at a given branch. Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Disclaimer:

*In the following answer, I assume that you mean:*

> We need to get all the **branch names** for the **selected repository** in
>   Github through LibGit2Sharp library.

#### Use the Branches property of the Repository Class

The following program with use the **`Repository.Branches`** property and then iterate on it:

```
class Program
{
    // Tested with LibGit2Sharp version 0.21.0.176
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Load the repository with the path (Replace E:\mono2 with a valid git path)
        Repository repository = new Repository(@"E:\mono2");
        foreach (var branch in repository.Branches)
        {
            // Display the branch name
            System.Console.WriteLine(branch.Name);
        }
        System.Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The output of the program will display something like that:

```
origin/mono-4.0.0-branch 
origin/mono-4.0.0-branch-ServiceModelFix
upstream/mono-4.0.0-branch-c5sr2
```

If you need something else like the `Remote` or the `UpstreamBranchCanonicalName` of a branch, you have the related property.

Comment: **We need to get all the repository names for the selected Branch in Github through LibGit2Sharp library.** This is what we need Fab.

Comment: @Skyrim. What do you mean by repository names ? repository in git means a local clone of the remote hosted in Github. By the way, libgit2sharp makes you able to query a local clone not dynamically request github remote data like for example the forks of a given repo.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a guess and assume that you mean the following:

***Try to list all the files and directories for a given repository.***

This would essentially mean that you want to run the command: git ls-files

I have referred the following link : https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/Git-ls-files

The following code snip should do the trick:

```
using System;
using LibGit2Sharp;

class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var repo = new Repository(@"C:\Repo"))
        {
            foreach (IndexEntry e in repo.Index)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", e.Path, e.StageLevel);
            }
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I would also like to add that, if you know the git command, then you can find the corresponding api on the [github project wiki](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/) for libgit2sharp:

Hope this helps.

Best.